# HTML 5 difference input id and input name?

Tags: html, input

I'm busy with something for school in HTML 5.

So here is my bit of code

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="your name" required><br>
```

So my question actually is:

What is the difference between the NAME and the ID? purpose? which one is more important?

Comment: Another thing, by the way : "name" is a reserved word in javascript, and it might lead you to buggy behaviors.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In short, the `name` is the identifier that is sent to the server when you submit the form. The `id` is a unique identifier for the browser, clientside, for javascript and such.

Answer (score 20):

The `name` attribute is for submitting a form element to the server; many elements may share the same `name` (e.g. radio buttons, which **must** have the same name within the set).

The `id` attribute is for uniquely identifying any element (not just form elements). It **must** be unique throughout the entire document.

Comment: And: A common, good practice to prevent brain-overload is to use the same value for the id and the name, when both are needed.  (And, use that same name as variables in php/javascript programs that hold denoting the node or its value, and also keep it similar to the label shown on the page.)  For radio-buttons (where the name is shared across several nodes/ids), use obviouslycorresponding names, eg `name="buttons" id="buttons-yes"`.

Answer (score 8):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique in your document. Only one element can have a given id. `document.getElementById()` finds the first element with the given `id`.

The `name` attribute is used by forms as the key in a key/value pair when submitting the form. The `value` attribute is both displayed in the browser, and submitted with the form.

Neither is "more important," they're just different. If you have an XML mindset, they're both just attributes on a node. In HTML they have more meaning though.