# HTML5 elements id vs name attributes

Tags: html

1. Could anybody kindly explain me the difference or logic behind HTML5 **id** & **name** attributes of input & other elements.
2. Should I define both or one is enough?
3. Which one is required? **id** or **name**

Comment: I think answer to my question available under: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165908/html-5-difference-input-id-and-input-name

Obtain from that post:

In short, the name is the identifier that is sent to the server when you submit the form. 

The id is a unique identifier for the browser, client-side, for JavaScript and such. Further more id attribute is for uniquely identifying any element (not just form elements). It must be unique throughout the entire document.

Comment: @BoldClock I think duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165908/html-5-difference-input-id-and-input-name rather than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397592/difference-between-id-and-name-attributes-in-html

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, both can be used for the same purpose. But,
Normally id attribute is used to call that element. and name attribute is used when you send a data to some other page from a form through post or get method, then we can access to the data of that element through that name.

Comment: No, the purpose of name and id is not the same anywhere; it hasn't been since last century.

Comment: I know its the same. I just said that we normally do that.